# PyQt - Event Binding (calling a function when the QCloseEvent occurs) - Procedural Style

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I know how this can be done OOP style, but am interested in fully understanding PyQt by seeing how the GUI toolkit can be programmed in both an object orientated and a procedural way.

My question is how can I bind the application closing event (click app cross) to the function in the code below? How can it be called when the application is quit?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QToolTip,
    QPushButton, QApplication, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


def closeEvent(event):
    reply = QMessageBox.question(w, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
        QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()

w.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
w.setWindowTitle('Procedural event binding - PyQt')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just overwrite the existing `closeEvent` of the widget:

```
w.closeEvent = closeEvent
```

and that will work in your example.

If you want a bound method, you can do:

```
import types
...

def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
    ...

w.closeEvent = types.MethodType(closeEvent, w)
```